# Promise.race crash - expected or v8 bug?

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, v8

This function will eat memory and eventually crash node. Is that the expected behavior or a bug in v8?

```js
async function crash() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    await Promise.race(new Array(10000));
  }
}
```

I'm guessing every iteration creates 10,000 new tasks but only waits for 1 of them to execute leaving 9,999 tasks behind which will accumulate and fill up the memory. But shouldn't those left behind tasks get executed and therefore be removed from memory once `Promise.race` is called in the next iteration?

Comment: @danh: The `Promise.race` call happens inside a loop which will loop back around and start another job if there is more to do.

Comment: Sorry @Jake, I just re-read and removed my errant comment before I saw your reply

Comment: Did you try using `async`/`await` for handling promises from `sendSomeRequest`? It simplifies the code and make easier to understand

Comment: @FadiHania: I don't see how that would work or how it would simplify the code and make it easier to understand. Can you show me what you have in mind?

Comment: @Jake, why do you use `Promise.race()` on `inFlight`?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a bug *in V8*: if you run the test in V8's `d8` shell, memory consumption remains low; there are many minor GC cycles freeing short-lived garbage. I don't know what Node might be doing differently.